# API Gateway intermittently returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present..." when the CORS OPTIONS request completes successfully

Tags: c#, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, kestrel-http-server

I'm at a complete loss for what's going on now.  I've been reading posts about API Gateway CORS for hours and they all boil down to the same basic thing.  You have not enabled the OPTIONS request appropriately on your API; something I am 99% sure I've done correctly at this point.

I'm working with a Lambda hosted Kestrel API provided by the Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer library mapped via API Gateway. I currently have it hosted in a private subnet where it has internet access provided via a NAT Gateway, all of this has been tested via EC2 instances launched in the private subnet. I have the API Gateway working on api.example.com while the actual website is hosted at example.com via S3 static website hosting.

CORS has been enabled on both the Kestrel Web API in the Startup class and in the API Gateway mapping, both of which are allowing all paths.  I've been struggling with the decision on whether or not to enable CORS on the API Gateway layer as I've read that with API Gateway Proxy integration, you can simply offload all the CORS validation to the Lambda layer, which would make sense instead of duplicating the CORS validation in 2 separate places (API Gateway & Web API).

From my web client, I'm able to make requests against the API without issue most of the time.  It appears that when I give it enough time, a subsequent requests is destined to fail.  I fire off an "activation" call to the Lambda when the user lands on the page in order to prevent long-load times on any subsequent actions.  This should ensure the user is working with a hot lambda or a frozen lambda instead of a cold lambda.  The problem seems to arise after a few minutes go by and the previous lambda instance may no longer exist.

If I load the page, the lambda should be activated.  If I give it a little bit of time, then attempt to submit Contact Information, I usually end up receiving a request failure.  The developer console indicates that the error is due "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present..."; however, there are specific times in which I can see the options request passing, but the failing response does not contain the access-control-allow-origin header.

I'm at an absolute loss, if anybody else can help explain the inconsistency that I'm seeing, that would be greatly appreciated.  This would be a million times easier if Lambda would stop raising C language errors in CloudWatch in my C# application.  I'm getting really frustrated with Lambda and starting to think of going with alternate hosting methodologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although my answer is relatively quick, this post was a last ditch effort after days of researching.  Turns out the issue isn't truly related to CORS, but it's related to the use of the async context within the Startup.cs class.

The failure that this question was about was specifically on an async POST method.  This app is still in its early stages, so there weren't a lot of async methods for me to play with.  I had assumed it was a higher level failure; however, it was actually a failure of the async context at the controller level.

I had attempted to use an async method in the Startup.cs class to assist with the initialization of a Singleton service.  The Task.WaitAll usage in this startup class destroyed the asynchronous context for the entire application.  Turns out, any attempts I had to await an async invocation would cause a failure.  In the end, all of this sourced to the use of the async method in my startup class.

As soon as I removed my async startup method, I was able to hit my API without issue. The failure that intermittently occurred during the population of the CORS method was due to the failing asynchronous context; however, since it occurred while requesting the OPTIONS method, it attributed the failure to CORS.

Lesson of the day: If you wish to instantiate a Kestrel API in a Lambda Microservice using the package Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer, you BETTER NOT USE ASYNC OR TASK IN Startup.cs